# Question about generalizing a system

Tags: ros, roslaunch, namespace, best-practices

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question is about the best practices when generalizing a working ROS stack.  I have a system that has many nodes working together to control a dynamic system.  There is a vision processing node, an estimation node, a controller node, a wireless communication node, and a keyboard interface node (that allows the user to control all of the rest of the system).  The way that the system runs is that there are a few rosparams that govern everything.  For instance, there is a param that says what state the system is in e.g. calibration, running, idling, etc.;  there is a param that says where the robot is supposed to start in a world frame (used for calibration and initializing an ekf); and there is a param that sets an index that tells my wireless system which robot I am talking to.

I have this system fully debugged and working nicely, and now I am looking to run multiple robots at the same time.  I could make a parameter that specifies the number of robots I'm using, and then in every node add for-loops around all of the relevant pieces of code to handle multiple robots.  However it seems to me that there should be a far easier solution.  If I can just start up multiple instances of each node, and then have each node only have access to parameters in its own namespace, then I can create the functionality I want by just creating a bit more complicated launch file.

Does this seem possible?  Where should I go to look for examples?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27515/question-about-generalizing-a-system/) by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9031 on 2012-02-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easiest ways to do this is to use the `<group>` tag in a roslaunch XML. You can find that documentation [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/group). Essentially, it would just launch each "system" (aka group of nodes) under a unique namespace. Thus, each robot would operate with its own set of parameters, and your launch file is actually quite simple.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1